# JWT signature does not match locally computed signature - only happens when bearer token is incorrect

Tags: java, kotlin, authentication, spring-security, jwt

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong. When passing the correct Bearer token everything works fine. But, when trying to invoke an "Unauthorized" by passing the wrong token I get :
`JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.`

My code:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts 
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm 
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component 
import java.io.Serializable import java.security.Key 
import java.util.*

@Component class JwtTokenUtil : Serializable {

private val serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L

fun getUsernameFromToken(token: String?): String {
    return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject)
}

fun getExpirationDateFromToken(token: String?): Date {
    return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration)
}

fun <T> getClaimFromToken(token: String?, claimsResolver: (Claims) -> T): T {
    val claims: Claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token)
    return claimsResolver(claims)
}

private fun getAllClaimsFromToken(token: String?): Claims {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder()
        .setSigningKey(key)
        .build()
        .parseClaimsJws(token)
        .body
}

private fun isTokenExpired(token: String?): Boolean {
    val expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token)
    return expiration.before(Date())
}

fun generateToken(userDetails: UserDetails): String? {
    val claims: Map<String, Any> = HashMap()
    return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.username)
}

private fun doGenerateToken(claims: Map<String, Any>, subject: String): String? {
    return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .setExpiration(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
        .signWith(key).compact()
}

fun validateToken(token: String?, userDetails: UserDetails): Boolean {
    val username = getUsernameFromToken(token)
    return username == userDetails.username && !isTokenExpired(token)
}

companion object {
    const val JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = (5 * 60 * 60).toLong()
    val key: Key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
}

}
```

And in Filter:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
import java.io.IOExceptionimport javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@Componentclass JwtTokenFilter(private val jwtUserDetailsService: JwtUserDetailsService,private val jwtTokenUtil: JwtTokenUtil) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

@Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
    val requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization")
    var username: String? = null
    var jwtToken: String? = null
    // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
    // only the Token
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7)
        println(jwtToken)
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            println("Unable to get JWT Token")
        } catch (e: ExpiredJwtException) {
            println("JWT Token has expired")
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String")
    }
    // Once we get the token validate it.
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication == null) {
        val userDetails: UserDetails = jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)

        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            val usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails,
                null,
                userDetails.authorities
            )
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.details = WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response)
}

}
```

My security config:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
import se.chorus.acceptusemail.security.JwtException
import se.chorus.acceptusemail.security.JwtTokenFilter
import se.chorus.acceptusemail.security.JwtUserDetailsService

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration(
    private val jwtUserDetailsService: JwtUserDetailsService,
    private val jwtException: JwtException,
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
    private val jwtTokenFilter: JwtTokenFilter
) {

    @Bean
    @Throws(java.lang.Exception::class)
    fun authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration: AuthenticationConfiguration): AuthenticationManager? {
        return authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager
    }

    @Autowired
    @Throws(java.lang.Exception::class)
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.userDetailsService<UserDetailsService>(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    @Bean
    protected fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests { requests ->
                requests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/authenticate", "/register").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtException).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            }

        return http.build()
    } // ...

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): UserDetailsService? {
        val user: UserDetails = User.withUsername("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build()
        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user)
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the "key" to a constant secret and also tried various approaches where I use a constant secret encoded to bytearray.

It seems like nothing changes my issue.

Edit:
I would like it to throw 401 Unauthorized instead of 500 as it does now. I don't understand why I get a signature exception when it should be an unauthorized exception. As I have set up in my config

```
        @Throws(Exception::class)
    @Bean
    protected fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests { requests ->
                requests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/authenticate", "/register").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtException).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            }
```

My exception class:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.io.IOException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@Component
class JwtException : AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun commence(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        authException: AuthenticationException
    ) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the real problem in more detail. You wrote *passing the wrong token I get : JWT signature does not match locally computed signature* - I would expect the described behavior for a wrong token, what did you expect instead?

Comment: First you do `jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(...)`, which already seems to validate the token and  there you only catch `ExpiredJwtException` but not the signature exception. Later you call `jwtTokenUtil.validateToken` and don't catch any exceptions. So the 500 seems justified. You should explicitly catch the signature exception (an other exceptions) as well, and also reconsider the structure of your code with two validations.

Comment: But I should not get signature exception, I don't see why I get it? The signature should be fine?

Comment: The signature is based on the header and payload part of the token, if they are changed so is the signature, therefore, it will not match.

Comment: You only mentioned *passing the wrong token*, so what is a wrong token here? Please explain that. If the key used to create the signature is not the same as the key used to verify, it would cause a signature exception. But you should generally be prepared for all kinds of exceptions.